# Split routed component to two outlets

Tags: angular

I'm wondering if is possible to split component to two router outlets?
For example, I have two not nested router outlets:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  
<router-outlet name="second"></router-outlet>
```

, route with specific component, which contains:

```
<div #a></div>
<div #b></div>
```

And after navigating to path `div#A` goes to `<router-outlet>` while `div#B` goes to `<router-outlet name="second">`.

Or maybe there is better way of passing some HTML data to component, which lays outside `<router-outlet>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split the content between two router-outlets you will need to decompose your template into two separate components, and then setup your routes for using named router outlets.

#### Example

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: OutletAComponent,
    outlet: 'a',
  },
  {
    path: 'view',
    component: OutletBComponent,
    outlet: 'b',
  },
];

@NgModule({imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], exports: [RouterModule]})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Next we need a component which hosts our two router-outlets

```html
  <!-- app.component.html -->
  <a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { a: ['view'], b: ['view'] } }]">Go to view</a>
  <router-outlet name="a"></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="b"></router-outlet>
```

Note, the routes do not necessarily need to be the same, in this case `view` was just chosen for both to illustrate how you would setup a router outlet with two routes.

The important aspect is merely to understand that the `outlets` prop has key values which must match with the desired router-outlet name, and the accompanying value will be the desired route.

See Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vvdvtc

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if there's a way to make path `/view` not `(a:view//b:view)`?

Comment: I do not think so. At least not if you want to use two router-outlets. You can create a similar layout using projected content and templates, but that's a little more involved and the details of how to go about it would largely depend on what exactly you're trying to achieve.